# How to get twig global in Silex?

Tags: php, frameworks, twig, global, silex

So, I'm using the Silex framework and Twig. I can set a variable in my php route which I can use inside the template. I'm using this line of code:

```
$app['twig']->addGlobal('loggedIn', 'false');
```

But now I'd like to know how to use this global in my php script again so that I can say:

```
if(!isset "twigglobal['loggedIn']"){
    $app['twig']->addGlobal('loggedIn', 'false');
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get all global vars from twig:

```
$twigglobals = $app['twig']->getGlobals();

if (!isset($twigglobals['loggedIn'])) {
    $app['twig']->addGlobal('loggedIn', 'false');
}
```